# Generating Large Prime Numbers for Diffie-Hellman in Ruby

Tags: ruby, cryptography, diffie-hellman

I'm writing an implementation of a diffie-hellman key exchange in ruby for a project for one of my university classes. I need to generate large (secure) prime numbers of at least 500 bits length. Any ideas? Should I use the OpenSSL library? If so, what functions would you recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the openssl gem

OpenSSL::BN::rand

You can specify the size you need - like so OpenSSL::BN::rand(212)

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Where can I find the documentation on this? I've checked ruby-doc.org but all I can find is stuff on OpenSSL::HMAC and a few others.

Comment: Also, is there a function that makes sure it's prime?

Comment: Also try OpenSSL::BN::generate_prime(500)

Comment: in terms of documention look at openssl documentation rather than the gem

Comment: I cannot see BN_is_prime in the ruby openssl gem. You could file a bug to add that or add that to the gem yourself.

Answer (score 0):

`OpenSSL::BN::generate_prime(500)` will do it, like abdollar said.
Make sure to put `require 'openssl'` at the top to include it in your ruby file

To check it is the correct number of bits you can print out the binary by just running `OpenSSL::BN::generate_prime(500).to_i.to_s(2).length` and it will print out 500, and the leading bit will be a 1

[Open SSL Documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/BN.html#)